# Wordpress multisite with same content

Tags: multisite, themes, network-admin

Trying to accomplish the following. Any help / advice is greatly appreciated.

1) I have multiple domain names (e.g., site1.com, site2.com, site3.com).
2) I need each domain to display the same content BUT
3) Show a different wordpress theme.Plugins are same...etc

Thank you

Comment: You can use a XML export of pages, menus, and then import data for a new site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want to concurrency update the both sites using one backend.That's what I want too. But theme is different.

Comment: XML export/import only imports a your demo content from your global site. That is a easy way to make a content to be cloned. All pay skins,themes, come with the demo data, attachemnts, and so on.  You can look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen

Answer (score 1):

This would take a little bit of work, but you could adapt code from this plugin:

http://www.mihaivalentin.com/different-wordpress-theme-depending-of-the-current-user/

First you would point all the domains to the same site.

This plugin changes the current theme depending on the user logged in.  But you could change the logic to change the theme depending on the referrer address.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'site1.com' ):
//one theme
elseif( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'site2.com'):
//another theme
endif;
```